# Copying ng-grid data as TSV

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'd like to copy the text in ng-grid as Tab Separated Values [TSV] but right now
it has 1 item per row. For example:

```
| A | B | C |
| D | E | F |
```

becomes

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

rather than

```
A    B    C
D    E    F
```

Best if this worked for Ctrl-C as well as Right-Click | Copy.

Any Angular or jQuery plugins which do this or code recommendations/samples?

Currently planning to override oncontextmenu for right-clicks, but will not be able to access $scope unless there is a way to handle right clicks using ng-click.

Comment: I stumbled on this CSV export in the plugins folder the other day but haven't given it shot yet, seems like it's probably a good jumping point though: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/plugins/ng-grid-csv-export.js Yup looks like you can just replace the , with a \t and be all set I think.

Comment: I've seen that one recently as well, but I need to copy & paste the code rather than download. I'll use that as a basis and then override oncontextmenu (for right-click) and use a jQuery or Flash plugin for Ctrl-C copying to the clipboard.